# Bcrypt may be create same hash for inputs? - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, bcrypt

Bcrypt may be create same hash for inputs?
Is that possible bcrypt create hash for 'abc' and 'egf' same password?

Comment: What you're describing is called a _collision_.

Comment: @firstOne, yes. But what I think he wanted to know is IF is possibile such thing. So, if bcrypt creates the hash for an input, is possibile (even remotely) that the function returns the same hash for another input? I am not sure, but I think is possible. Since I'm not sure I will not answer, but yes, it is a collision, if happens. But what the OP meant is if was even possible

Comment: I know what's been asked and it's at least off-topic - I might even say that googling it could give some results. @Optiroot

Answer (score 3):

For any hashing algorithm, or any algorithm with a finite output space and an infinite input space, there will be an infinite number of inputs that produce the same output.

Is this a problem? No, not really. The only thing we care about is that the same password produces the same hash and that it is very unlikely to ever get the same hash with any other password. It is very unlikely to find two input strings that produce the same bcrypt hash.